# Why /sys/block/zram0/comp_algorithm not exist?

Tags: kernel, zram

See  [zram kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/zram.txt)  we know there should have /sys/block/zram0/comp_algorithm

```
Examples:
    #show supported compression algorithms
    cat /sys/block/zram0/comp_algorithm
    lzo [lz4]

    #select lzo compression algorithm
    echo lzo > /sys/block/zram0/comp_algorithm
```

But my physical host /sys/block/zram0/comp_algorithm this file not exist ,Why?

```
#lsmod  | grep zram
zram                   18525  1


#ll /sys/block/zram0/
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 alignment_offset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 15 11:43 bdi -> ../../bdi/252:0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 capability
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 compr_data_size
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 dev
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 discard_alignment
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:44 disksize
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 ext_range
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Aug 15 11:43 holders
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 inflight
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 initstate
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 invalid_io
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 mem_used_total
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 notify_free
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 num_reads
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 num_writes
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 orig_data_size
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Aug 15 11:43 power
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Aug 15 11:43 queue
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 range
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 removable
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 reset
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 ro
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 size
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Aug 15 11:43 slaves
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 stat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 15 11:43 subsystem -> ../../../../class/block
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Aug 15 11:43 trace
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:41 uevent
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:43 zero_pages
```

Comment: I find solution zram algorithm attribution is from kernel v3.15 support , but , before  kernel v3.15  what compress algorithm use ?

Comment: IIRC, zram was available before 3.15 but you had to patch the kernel and compile it yourself...and probably not too much before (i.e. probably not for any 2.6.x kernel).  I'd suggest upgrading to at least 3.15 rather than trying that.  Useful reading at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zswap